# Excel VBA: Printing x copies each with an increasing number in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to either:

- Increase a number in a cell each time a page has been printed: e.g. print 20 pages with numbers from 1-20 in the cell

  or if that isn't possible:
- Run a For-loop, each increasing the number and each time prompting the printer to print.

I know this is a very basic question, but bear with me - It is the 1st time I'm trying my luck  at Excel macros.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can be put into '**ThisWorkbook**' object to increment a cell value each time something from the workbook is printed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: The 'BeforePrint' event is available from Excel 97 forward

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a VBA Macro to populate and print a worksheet.  For Excel 2010, use the Developer ribbon to Record Macro.  It will record the steps you want in a Visual Basic macro, which you can then edit.  You can change the macro to use a For-loop, changing the worksheet each time before you print.